# iOS simulator is black and application doesn't install

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I am just trying to run a simple hello world application but the simulator is just displaying a black screen.
I have read several forums and followed solutions recommended but none worked.

I tried the following;

1. Cleaning the project
2. Deleting the app from the simulator
3. Restart the simulator
4. Removed `/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/` files

But none worked.

Is there any solution for this ?

**Note:** OS version Mac OS 10.9
Xcode 5.0.1
Simulator : Version 7.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a know issue in XCode 5.0.1

> If an iOS app running in the simulator is detached, a relaunch of the same app from Xcode will result in a black screen in iOS Simulator even though the new instance of the app is launched.
>   Terminate the app in the simulator, or relaunch it a second time. 14648784

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-SW241

Comment: If the screen is always black also with this workaround, there may be a problem in your code. You need to post some code in that case, more specifically the `ApplicationDidFinishLaunching:` could be good

Answer (score 0):

Menu -> iOS simulator -> Reset content and settings. This works for me at all times